# pulling data from one mongodb collection into another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have created a mongodb collection for a list of drinks The schema is below.  In it I have made a drink list that users can choose from.

```
 var drinkSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  date: {
    type:Date,
    // default: new Date()
    default: Date.now()

  },
  caffeineLevel: String
});

var Drink = mongoose.model('Drink',drinkSchema);

module.exports = Drink;
```

I also created a second schema for users of my app.  Ideally the user would be able to move data into this schema by selecting a drink from the other schema. This schema would be unique to each user.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var myDrinkSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  date: {
    type:Date,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  caffeineLevel: String
  // drinkWant: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Drink'}]
});

var myDrink = mongoose.model('myDrink',myDrinkSchema);

module.exports = myDrink;
```

I apologize that I do not have more knowledge of the matter.  I searched through the documents and came across data modeling  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/.  But this did not seem to have a specific answer.

Is it possible to do this in a schema method?

Answer (score 0):

You have it right, however just because you specify a reference to another collection doesn't mean mongoose will populate it for you. You actually have to specify which field/s you want to populate and it will populate those fields based on the `ref` of that field in the schema. If you uncomment `drinkWant` array and fill it with `Drink` _id's then you should be able to `.populate()` your results.

You simply just have to chain `.populate()` after running a query. For example:

```
myDrink.find({name: "someName"}).populate('drinkWant')
   .exec(function(err, results) {
      console.log(results);
});
```

For more information [see here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).